# If the mother group has $1000$ people with the female ratio of $30$%, how is it likely that a sample of $200$ could contain less than 5 females?

Tags: probability, statistics

I believe the calculation would be like below:

$$
\dfrac{(1000-200)!200!}{1000!} \sum_{j=0}^5[\dfrac{300!}{(300-j)!j!} \cdot  \dfrac{700!}{(700-200+j)!(200-j)!}]
$$

- The first $\dfrac{(1000-200)!200!}{1000!} $ is reciprocal of entire number of cases.
- $\sum_{j=0}^5$ takes the summation over each case with number of females in the $200$ people sample to be $0$ to $5$.
- The equation inside the [] parenthesis calculates all possible combinations of female and male samples within the given constraint.

I wonder if the math is correct, and if it is correct, is there any good way to numerically solve it with high precision?
I feel like the number could get so big and cause possible floating-point error.

Comment: Formula’s now right. Sum up logs of terms for each term if you’re worried about overflow.

Comment: Is there a reason you care about solving this exactly, rather than just using concentration inequalities?

Comment: Could anyone can indicate a standard way to solve it then?
I thought it could be solved numerically, using high performance computing method. But if you can derive a good enough answer with just pencil and paper it would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the number of females in the sample. I would read the question as asking for the probability $P(X < 5)$, which is equal to $P(X \leq 4)$,
but you are calculating $P(X \leq 5)$.
Either way, an exact solution can be obtained with technology somewhere between
pencil-and-paper and a high-speed computer.
I used an Excel spreadsheet.

We can use binomial coefficients, $\dbinom nr = \dfrac{n!}{(n - r)!r!}$,
to write your version of the calculation more succinctly:

$$
P(X \leq 5) =
 \frac1{\dbinom{1000}{200}} \sum_{j=0}^5
\left[\binom{300}{j} \cdot \binom{700}{200-j}\right].
$$

In order to explain how to simplify the calculations, I think it will help if we can use the concepts of *falling factorial* and *rising factorial*.
The falling factorial is represented by the notation $(x)_n$, defined by
\begin{align}
(x)_0 &= 1, \\
(x)_n &= x(x - 1)\cdots(x - n + 1) & \text{when $n > 0$.}
\end{align}
The rising factorial is represented by the notation $x^{(n)}$, defined by
\begin{align}
x^{(0)} &= 1, \\
x^{(n)} &= x(x + 1)\cdots(x + n - 1) & \text{when $n > 0$.}
\end{align}
That is, either the falling or rising factorial is the product of $n$ consecutive integers, but the falling factorial $(x)_n$ is the product of a **decreasing** sequence of $n$ integers starting with $x$,
whereas the rising factorial $x^{(n)}$ is the product of an **increasing** sequence of $n$ integers starting with $x$.

Canceling out some of the identical factors that occur on top and bottom of the various fractions, we can use falling factorials to describe the remaining factors:

$$
\frac{1}{\dbinom{1000}{200}}
= \frac{(1000-200)!200!}{1000!} = \frac{200!}{(1000)_{200}}, \\
\binom{300}{j} = \frac{300!}{(300-j)!j!} =  \frac{(300)_j}{j!},\ \text{and} \\[2ex]
\binom{700}{200-j}
 = \frac{700!}{(700-200+j)!(200-j)!} =  \frac{(700)_{200-j}}{(200-j)!}. 
$$

Another way to express the last equation is to look at what factors are included in the case where $j = 0$ that are not included in other cases, and use falling and rising factorials to cancel those factors out of the $j = 0$ case for each other $j$.
For $j = 1$ we lose a factor of $501$ in the numerator and $200$ in the denominator,
for $j = 2$ we lose $501\cdot 502$ in the numerator and $200\cdot 199$ in the denominator, and so forth. Therefore

$$
\binom{700}{200-j} = \frac{(700)_{200-j}}{(200-j)!} =
  \frac{(700)_{200}}{200!} \cdot \frac{(200)_j}{501^{(j)}}  .
$$

Putting this together,
\begin{align}
P(X \leq 5)
&= \frac{200!}{(1000)_{200}} \sum_{j=0}^5
\left[\frac{(300)_j}{j!} \cdot
 \frac{(700)_{200}}{200!} \cdot \frac{(200)_j}{501^{(j)}}\right] \\
&= \frac{(700)_{200}}{(1000)_{200}}
 \sum_{j=0}^5 \left[\frac{(300)_j}{j!} \cdot \frac{(200)_j}{501^{(j)}}\right].
\end{align}

Now $\dfrac{(700)_{200}}{(1000)_{200}}$ is not too hard to compute if you
take one factor at a time from both numerator and denominator:

$$
\frac{(700)_{200}}{(1000)_{200}} =
\left( \frac{700}{1000} \right) \left( \frac{699}{999} \right)
 \left( \frac{698}{998} \right)  \cdots \left( \frac{501}{801}\right).
$$

Working out each fraction before multiplying, we have to multiply together $200$ numbers, but all these numbers are between $0.625$ and $0.7$ and we never get a result that cannot be handled by most floating-point software.

The terms in the sum are even easier to calculate, since in the worst case
(when $j = 5$) you have ten factors in the numerator and ten factors in the denominator.
A little work with a spreadsheet shows that

\begin{align}
\frac{(700)_{200}}{(1000)_{200}} &\approx 3.80376 \times 10^{-36}, \\
 \sum_{j=0}^4 \left[\frac{(300)_j}{j!} \cdot \frac{(200)_j}{501^{(j)}}\right]
&\approx 8339051.331,\ \text{and} \\
 \sum_{j=0}^5 \left[\frac{(300)_j}{j!} \cdot \frac{(200)_j}{501^{(j)}}\right]
&\approx 193400023.2.
\end{align}

Therefore
$$ P(X \leq 4) \approx 3.17197\times 10^{-29} $$
and
$$ P(X \leq 5) \approx 7.35647\times 10^{-28}. $$

Comment: Separating the terms that way is clever. This technique must be useful dealing with a probability questions on the same line. Thanks a lot!